# Faster server response

Tags: mysql, innodb

What should be the correct value for innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit if I want to make the query faster at any cost? 
I do not bother about data integrity at this moment. I have set the following in my.cnf

```
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 0 is slightly faster than 2, but less durable.  If you are just reimporting data = 0 is fine, but the savings are not (usually) high enough to toleration the added losses.

If you want to disable a bunch of features for speed here they are:

- innodb_doublewrite = 0
- innodb_checksums = 0
- innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog
- (session) SET foreign_key_checks = 0
- log-bin = 0
- innodb_support_xa = 0

Not that I don't recommend any of this.  Please be careful with this advice, it is not for production.